# Fetching with response from a previous fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am currently trying to call an API with the response of a previous API fetch.

First, I call the method `fetchRoster`. Then, for every player on the roster (NHL), I would love to use it's id to fetch his stats from another endpoint.

```
var roster = await fetchRoster(8);


roster.map((player) => {
  console.log(player.person.id);
  console.log(player.person.fullName);

  var stats = getPlayerStats(player.person.fullName);
  console.log(stats);
})
```

This is the method `fetchRoster()` that I call first to get the IDs of the players.

```
async function fetchRoster(id) {
    try {
        //let response = await fetch(`${roster_base_url}/${id}/roster `);
        let response = await fetch('https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams/' + id + '/roster');
        let responseJson = await response.json();
        return responseJson.roster;
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

This is the method `getPlayersStats` that is called after obtaining the id from the first API response.

```
export async function getPlayerStats(id) {
try {
    let response = await fetch('https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/people/' + id + '/stats?stats=statsSingleSeason&season=20192020');
    let responseJson = await response.json();
    return responseJson.stats[0].splits[0].stat;
} catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
}
}

)
```

However, it seems that the first response isn't arrived yet when calling the 2nd API. Does anyone have a solution for that?

Is it possible to call await on `getPlayersStats()` although it's inside `.map` which is not async?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that `fetchRoster()` must be `async`:

```js
async function fetchRoster(id) {
    try {
        //let response = await fetch(`${roster_base_url}/${id}/roster `);
        let response = await fetch('https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams/' + id + '/roster');
        let responseJson = await response.json();
        return responseJson.roster;
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Then `fetchRoster()` will return `Promise` that works with `await`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var roster = await fetchRoster(8);


roster.map((player) => {

  var stats = getPlayerStats(player.person.fullName);
  // Here getPlayerStats is a promise. So it does not work
  console.log(stats); 
})
```

You can try something like this

```
var roster = await fetchRoster(8);

var stats = await Promise.all(roster.map(player => getPlayerStats(player.person.fullName))

console.log(stats); // Now stats is a list of response.
```

More about this: https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-await-array-map/